# TextView not updating

Tags: java, android, google-maps, textview

I have a silly problem updating text in a `TextView` using a handler class. I'm setting custom Info window in Google Maps.

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
                //setting marker as final***
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
                TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);


                final TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);

                for(MyItem mi : myItems){
                    if(mi.getName().equals(marker.getTitle())){

                        name.setText(mi.getName()); //This one updates normaly

                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //this one sets the text, but doesnt update on UI
                                status.setText("Text"); 

                                //Here I call my update text function
                                updateTv(status, "Text");
                                //Refreshing the window***
                                marker.showInfoWindow();

                            }
                        }, 5000);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return v;
            }
        });
    }
```

`TextView` "name" is updating normally, while "status" `TextView` is only updating its content and not updating visually on the screen. I've tried invalidating, `runOnUiThread()`, but nothing seems to work. I know the solution might be really obvious, but I don't see it.

Thank you for your help in advance!

EDIT

Here's how i tried runOnUiThread().

```
public void updateTv(final TextView tv, final String s){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                tv.setText(s);

                tv.invalidate();

            }
        });
    }
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="..."
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SOLUTION

I refreshed my window by calling commands commented and signed with *** in the code above. My thanks goes to "clownba0t"

Comment: You should update UI element on the main thread. Show the code you used when you say you tried runOnUiThread().

Comment: Would you mind posting `R.layout.my_layout`?

Comment: your layout xml ? since name textView is working its probably has nothing to do with the updating mechanism, something wrong with mapping maybe!

Comment: mapping is fine, since i can change "status" TextView if i change it at the same time as I change name. I need to change it with a delay, and that causing me problems. The status.getText() shows me, that the text really changed, but UI doesnt.

Comment: So the `status` `TextView` just continues to show '...' on the screen even after `setText("Text")` has definitely run?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: I can't imagine this will have any impact on the issue, but as an aside, you don't really need a `Handler` here. The `View` class has a `postDelayed` method which you can use in the same fashion, so you could perhaps try `v.postDelayed` instead.

Comment: Also, when I tried your code locally in Android Studio, it showed an error saying that the `status` variable needs to be `final`. Interesting that yours doesn't. What development environment are you using?

Comment: v.postDelayed() is showing same results as Handler

Comment: @clownba0t yes, it is final, i accidentaly pasted it in here without it.

Comment: Could this be a problem with InfoWindowAdapter or google maps?

Comment: Heh, I just checked the documentation for `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents` and it says "If you change this view after this method is called, those changes will not necessarily be reflected in the rendered info window." I guess that explains it!

Comment: The documentation seems to contain some advice on how to update an info window - see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows).

Comment: clownba0t your are correct. The problem is, Info window isn's a "live" View, just an image. I am now refreshing it, and it works perfectly.  How do I mark your anwser as correct? :)

Comment: You can't - it's a comment, not an answer :) I suppose I could create an answer and you could mark that as accepted. You seem to have accepted Ahmad's answer already, though. Did `status.invalidate()` actually work for you? I thought you'd already tried that. How did you end up refreshing the info window?

Comment: Here is the explanation: http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-app-text-not-updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to update the view after it returned from `getInfoContents()` and that won't work as its not a live view, see [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#getInfoContents(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)).

Something that might work is calling:

```
status.invalidate();
```

Comment: status.invalidate() isn't working, however i marked your anwser as correct, since you explained about my View not being "live"

Comment: I have data from an API, currently using view model, this did the trick. This is weird though. I dont know why text wont get updated unless I set .invalidate()

Answer (score 1):

This came from the fact Android is an OS using messages. So there is a part of the OS which read messages and perform actions according to the order in the message.

Refreshing the text in the TextView is done by this way: when you perform setText() your code prepare a message and send it to the OS to tell him "Please refresh the textView"".

We can simplify the explanation saying you can send 10 letters to a friend, but even if you send the 10 letters at the same time, maybe they will not arrived at the same time...

And here, that's the case: for Android, messages for the User Interface are not "priority" messages. But App Code has a high priority.
So when you perform the setText() the message is sent, but the OS don't read it as, after the setText() you perform huge code action. So the OS run your code and only when this huge piece of code is finished, the OS say "Oh, well, maybe I received a letter", he open the letter find "Please refresh the textView" and do it.
So... AFTER you huge piece of code.

How to solve that?
You must put your huge piece of code in a handler.

```
  TextView tmp_id_top_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_top_clavier);
  tmp_id_top_msg.setText("message to display");

  Handler handler_spend_time;
  handler_spend_time = new Handler();
  handler_spend_time.postDelayed(Call_Huge_Code(), 100);
```

Then:

```
public Runnable Call_Huge_Code()
{
    return new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // here your code...
        }
    };
}
```

This will delay the execution of you code by 100 milliseconds which is not enought to "slow" the process but which is enought for Android to read the "refresh setText" message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
    status.setText("Some text");
    status.invalidate();
    status.requestLayout();
```