# TextView not updating in RFCOMM handler

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, rfcomm

I need to update a TextView based on the data I receive from the bluetooth rfcomm channel

This is the rfcomm handler function:

```
// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        txtViewDebug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView_textViewDebug);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                        // mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        //  mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);           // ORIGINALLY PRESENT
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                        // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);        // ORIGINALLY PRESENT
                        // mTitle.setText(R.string.not_connected);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                switch(rfcomm_state_flag){
                    case 0:
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        // current received data is the lower half of the CSR audio signal
                        for(int i=0; i<AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE; i++){
                            audio_sig_from_csr[i] = (short) readMessage.charAt(i);
                            // txtViewDebug.append(Integer.toHexString(audio_sig_from_csr[i] & 0xffff)  + "\n" ) ;
                            // txtViewDebug.setText(txtViewDebug.getText() + Integer.toHexString(audio_sig_from_csr[i] & 0xffff)  + "\n" );
                        }
                        txtViewDebug.append("Test value" + "\n") ;
                        // txtViewDebug.invalidate();

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // current received data is the upper half of the CSR audio signal
                        rfcomm_state_flag = 0;      // reset this flag to 0
                        for(int i=0; i<AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE; i++){
                            tempVar = (short) readMessage.charAt(i);
                            audio_sig_from_csr[i] += (tempVar << 8);
                        }

                        try {
                            for(int i=0;i <audio_sig_from_csr.length; i++)
                                // savToDisk.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(lin[i]));        // from wav file creator file
                                savToDisk.writeShort(audio_sig_from_csr[i] );
                            // payload += lin.length; // use this line if lin is an array of byte
                            // payload = payload + (lin.length)*2;
                            fd.sync();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(BluetoothChat.this, "File written", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }

                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                        + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

The project itself was based on the Bluetooth Chat sample program from android developer's website. I modified the Bluetooth chat program to send and receive rfcomm data from a custom bluetooth device

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
```

is where the incoming rfcomm data from the Bluetooth device is received as bytes

I change the byte `values` to `String` and then to `short`, which I want to display as hexadecimal values in a TextView to compare whether what I get from the rfcomm channel is the same value that was sent by the bluetooth device

My attempt at updating the TextView can be seen under `case 1:` in `case MESSAGE_READ:`

However, the TextView does not update whether I call the setText() function of the append() function.

The line

```
txtViewDebug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView_textViewDebug);
```

was in `onCreate()` but that didn't work either.

I tried calling `invalidate()` after reading about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573380/textview-not-updating) but that doesn't work either

Why isn't the TextView updating from inside this handler function? I added another command button to my interface and added a simple `txtViewDebug.setText()` and it works as expected, but I need to be able to update it with the values I receive in this handler function.

Why isn't the TextView updating and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text must be done on the ui thread 
so try wrapping the code inside a `runOnUiThread`